# Find where $r(t)=<t,t,t^2>$ hits the $x-y$ plane

Tags: vector-spaces

I have to find $r'(t)$ and $||r'(t)||$ for $r(t)=<t,t,t^2>$, which I know how to do.

$r'(t)=<1,1,2t>$
$||r'(t)||=\sqrt{2+4t^2}$

The problem is that my professor didn't explain how to find where each curve hits the $x-y$ plane (if it hits).

I'm guessing that I have to make $z=0$, but where?

Answer (score 1):

Your vector equation is also a set of parametric equations, $x(t) = t)$, $y(t) = t$, and $z(t) = t^2$.  Set $z = 0$ and obtain $t = 0$. This curve strikes the $xy$-plane at the origin.

Comment: I think I get it, but one more question: if $r(t)=<1+t,2+3t,4−2t>$, I set $z=0$, and obtain $t=4$. From here I plug in $t=4$ into the parametric equations, so the curve hits the $x−y$ plane at $(5,14,0)$?

Comment: Why is it $t=2$?